# Can the formula bar font in Excel 2011 be changed?

Tags: ms-office

Is it possible to change the font, specifically the size of the font, in the formula bar of Excel 2011?

I've found a number of resources to do this in the Windows version but none of those instructions seem to apply to the Mac version...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/837994-formula-bar-text-size.html

Seems like "no" for 2011.  Grr.. very frustrating!

Comment: Welcome to AD, and thank you for your answer. Would you be willing to summarize the information found at the link you provided? We prefer answers to be reasonably autonomous as external links can break over time. Links in answers are good, but link-only answers aren't.